# Sockets - getting and setting size of the receiving packet

Tags: java, c#, sockets

I've seen different approach on this one.
I have a server written in java and c# client.

Most of the data sending examples I've seen data is simply sent using:

**Sent from C# client**

```
TcpClient tcpClient = _tcpClient.Connect(ip, port);
NetworkStream stream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
BinaryWriter s = new BinaryWriter(stream);

//send some info
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{1,2,3}

//capsulated in thread
    s.Write(bytes);
    s.Flush();
```

And on received

**Received on Java server**

```
Socket socket = // create it on incoming connection
DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

//we create some magical size byte array
byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
input.read(bytes);
```

The problem is that magical size byte array doesn't really look like a solid solution. I hate creating thing which I cant control or don't know the content of.
So solution I came up with is sending the byte array size first

```
s.Write(bytes.length); //send int or byte array of the int value
s.Flush();
s.Write(bytes);
s.Flush();
```

and on receive

```
int size = input.readInt();
byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
input.read(bytes);
```

So now I have byte array which all content is completely filled.

I don't know why, but I have also doubts about this solution, must be because ive seen examples with first solution only. What do you think about second solution, are or might there be any problems with it you could see, maybe there are better solutions?

Comment: The receiving code is not legal Java. It doesn't compile. Question remains obscure. Are you perhaps looking for `DataInputStream.readFully()`? And a proper way to write the integer from the C# side?

Comment: Note that if this is TCP, there is no "packet size", TCP is a stream oriented protocol. On the other hand, if this is UDP, there is (and they're called "datagrams").

Comment: Question updated with fields

Comment: It still doesn't compile, after several updates.

Comment: Everything compiles fine. Remarkable is that you're repeating 'doesn't compile' several times, without mentioning what exactly is that you are asking.

Comment: Not this code. The result of `read()` is an `int`, which cannot be assigned to a variable of type `byte[]`. Visible by inspection and verifiable on test. What is truly remarkable is that you haven't spotted or encountered it yourself.

Comment: I had a typo  *bytes =* before  *input.read(bytes);*  which doesn't really change the question, as the question is not about error in the code, but solution for the problem. Which is knowing the byte array size before reading. @hotzenplotz clearly commented about the question like it should be done in this case.

Comment: A typo whose existence you repeatedly denied. @hotzenplotz certainly hasn't used this code, has he? You should be using `DataInputStream.readFully()`, as I suggested quite some time ago, and not assuming that `read()` fills the buffer. It isn't guaranteed to do that. See the Javadoc. And I doubt that your C# code works correctly for data larger than 255 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the readfully(), that's definitely a +1, but that still requires knowledge of the byte[] size. Do you think sending size before would be a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second solution is good. We have used this solution in more than ten projects

Comment: I mean sent packet size first, don't put emphasis in syntax